# "3 questions" in Stack Overflow comments pointing to Code Review

Tags: discussion

An SO user [commented this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811378/minimal-theme-feedback#comment49671490_30811378) on a question that would possibly be a candidate for Code Review:

> I think we need a three question quiz before you can post.

Of which it was said [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22165338#22165338):

> That's a distressingly reasonable idea

How could we word it so it's short enough for a comment, and friendly enough for the user to want to post it on CR instead of SO?

*Reminder: The character limit for comments is 600 characters.*

Comment: I think "Does your code work as expected" would be a good one, if we could phrase it so that "too slow/inefficient" could be "expected". Maybe "Does your code have any known bugs?"

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I believe it is better to have questions where "Yes" is the desired answer rather than "No". "Does your code work as expected" - Yes. "Does your code have any known bugs?" - No. Besides, not having known bugs does not imply that you have tested your code. If it works as expected, then you have tested it. And we do want users to test their code *before* posting a question.

Comment: "Does your code work?"  "As expected" could invoke a "no, it's too slow" response.

Comment: I am sorry to have distressed anyone with my reasonableness. :-p

Comment: It really is a distressingly reasonable idea... I find that in itself distressing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Taking a stab at it:

> This question could be suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

I think the repetition of *"your code"* kind of implies the "code that you own or maintain" condition. I think the last phrase wraps in the "review any/all aspects."

Copy/Paste-friendly version:

```
This question could be suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.
```

> (348 characters)

*Reminder: The character limit for comments is 600 characters.*

Comment: ...Man, I feel like I stole mine (updated answer) from you, even though I finished it before you finished yours

Comment: Doesn't matter, we're all doing this for the greater cause :)

Comment: "_delete your questions here_" That sounds... a _little_ vague, y'know? Like you want me to delete _all_ my Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I edited that part to make it singular

Comment: Perhaps you could make the "delete your question" part even less negative by just saying "please repost it on Code Review instead."

Comment: Should we emphasize "your" like this: `*your*` in case someone doesn't get it?

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) *your* code works as intended, (b) *your* code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) *your* code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review and delete your question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SirPython I could go either way, but I think the repetition of "your" is probably sufficient. The "somebody else's code" issue doesn't come up really that often

Answer (score 11):

They should probably each be short and encapsulate the idea that:

1. You want a review on every facet of the code, not just some.
2. The code in question works as intended.
3. The code in the question is actual code, not hypothetical or pseudocode.

[Phrancis brought up a good point in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22166413#22166413): There should also be something to the effect of

> If all three criteria are met, please *delete this question* and post it on Code Review.

Put all that together, and you get something like this:

> This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want *every aspect* of your code reviewed, not just some, (b) your code is *already working*, and (c) you're asking for a review of *concrete, real code*, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, delete it here and repost it on CR.

Or, in copypasta-friendly format:

```
This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want _every aspect_ of your code reviewed, not just some, (b) your code is _already working_, and (c) you're asking for a review of _concrete, real code_, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, delete it here and repost it on CR.
```

Reminder: The character limit for comments is 600 characters. The current one is **541** characters.

---

NOTE: This post is Community Wiki for a reason, but I'd appreciate it if you gave others a chance to provide input on changes by *commenting* before you edit, unless it's something trivial like fixing a spelling mistake.

Comment: Please see this comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/3-questions-in-so-comments-pointing-to-cr#comment12522_5468 . I'd rather see "Does your code work as intended?" as a question.

Comment: "Code is your own" doesn't come up that often, and it's kind of _implied_ when you say "Your code" in the "does it have known bugs" question

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Mind taking another look?

Comment: `(a) you want every aspect of your code reviewed, not just some` I don't think that part is enforced often enough to really warrant a part in this comment. And *if* it should be a part of the comment, it should definitely not be the first.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Good point. What would you suggest in its place? "You're asking for a review of existing features" maybe, to cover that advice about code to be written is OT?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes That's already a part of "works as intended". I think Phrancis' suggestion is better, where 'include code in question' is added.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but shouldn't it be "if you agree with all of these"? Not "all of those?"?

Comment: @holroy I'm a native speaker, and probably. Better phrasing would probably be "If all of these are correct" though.

Answer (score 7):

If we're going to be posting these kinds of comments, we should be careful not to steal questions from Stack Overflow that are actually on-topic for Stack Overflow.  (That's important: many Stack Overflow users (both newbies and veterans) don't understand what makes a question inappropriate for Stack Overflow, and they will get frustrated unless we explain why their question needs to be moved at all.)  I think that the [wording proposed for a standard off-topic reason](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313267/1157100) would serve our purpose well:

> Questions about existing working code must identify a **specific problem or concern**. Requests for **open-ended critique** to improve code that already works as intended may be appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

That covers two key criteria: the code must work, and the author must be receptive to suggestions for improvements in general.  Use your own judgement about whether the code looks too hypothetical or excessively reduced before posting the comment.

Markdown for copying:

`Questions about existing working code must identify a **specific problem or concern**. Requests for **open-ended critique** to improve code that already works as intended may be appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777).`

Answer (score 4):

#### A shorter, more focused one

This is only two questions/requirements, but it may be handy:

> This may be a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), so long as: **(A)** *the code works*, **and (B)** *it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way*. Please read the [on-topic guide](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting, if you choose to go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Postable version:

> ```
> This may be a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), so long as: **(A)** _the code works_, **and (B)** _it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way_. Please read the [on-topic guide](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting, if you choose to go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).
> ```

<sub>362 characters length</sub>