# Stack Overflow moderator declined to migrate question asking to shorten code

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, migration

According to the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), the following topics are wanted on Code Review:

[image]

Isn't there a point missing? I see a review of my code not only as an attempt to improve performance, security and structure, but also to reduce redundant, unnecessary code paths.

Isn't improving readability a major goal in a code review?

Specifically, I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311168/how-to-reduce-the-code-length-of-for-loop-in-python3) post, from which I think belongs on Code Review as there is no problem with it. My flag got declined because the moderator didn't see any evidence to intervene.

Comment: Yes, those things are also allowed, but not all mentioned in Tour. The site's scope is best covered in [ask].

Comment: Thanks. I just stumbled over [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) post. It basically answers my question, but I'm still confused. Should I flag a question on SO, which wants code to get shortened or not?

Comment: Generally speaking, code refactoring requests are frowned on over on SO because the OP is usually incapable of sufficiently clarifying the question in such a way that it would be useful to future visitors. (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295665/are-dry-questions-on-topic)..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, shortening code by reducing redundancy is within the scope of Code Review — it naturally falls under the category of general code improvements.

However, migrating a question involves a more complex decision-making process than you described.  Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/9357) for more information.

For the specific question you cited, the Stack Overflow moderator may have declined to migrate the question based on…

- Lack of evidence that the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Did you cite an **off-topic reason** in your flag?  (The moderator dismissed your flag without closing the question as off-topic, so it can be deduced that the moderator thinks it's on-topic for Stack Overflow.)
- Poor question quality (the **"Don't Migrate Crap"** rule).  The question basically consists of a code dump with no explanation of motivation.  What is `a`?  What does `length_wordlist` mean, and are there just two cases or is this an excerpt of 2 out of *n* cases?  The code looks like it might be incomplete, since the first case has `FILE.close()` but the second case does not.
- A comment by @jonrsharpe (a highly ranked Code Review member) encouraging the original author to **cross-post with clarifications**.  If @jonrsharpe had thought that the question was worthy of migration, he would likely have flagged it instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind for the next time.