# Is it OK to cross post here and in SO?

Tags: support, stackexchange

This is the dedicated realm in SE to post questions about reviewing one's code. But this is not a SE site that has many members in comparison to SO. The possibility to have this code review helped with is much higher on SO than it is on Code Review.

So I want to know, if it would be bad manners, if I posted the same question here and in SO?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not ok. Yes, it would be bad manners. On top of that, it would be quite an accomplishment to phrase a question such that it's on-topic and well-received both here *and* on Stack Overflow.

Please see our [FAQ on the differences](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915).

I understand your frustration. You have 3 questions on the site, some of them quite old, yet no answers. Perhaps our [FAQ on getting the best value out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2440/52915) can help you.

---

The on-topic help center for Code Review can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), for Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The Stack Exchange-wide FAQ (for all SE sites) on cross-posting can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/269301).

Comment: From the FAQ: `Just because a question is said to have "working code" and seems to be on-topic on Code Review, doesn't mean that it is automatically off-topic for Stack Overflow. There are many questions that are on-topic on both sites. The Stack Overflow Help Center doesn't say that code reviews are explicitly off-topic there [...]`

Comment: @yunzen Technically you're absolutely correct, so I've clarified my answer. Important information was still missing, I'm sorry :-)

Comment: @yunzen Please bare in mind that what's off-topic and what's against site policy are not the same. For example "thanks" in question bodies are against SO's site policy but having a "thanks" in the question doesn't make it off-topic. Similarly you _can_ post some questions on both SO and CR, but that doesn't make it right to do so.